# Rive file is taking to long to load in flutter

Tags: flutter, rive

Hallo I am developing a flutter app wit rive animations , Is it possibele to load a .Riv first with just one animation and load a bigger one in the backgroud and when it's finnished display run that one ?
Or should I have an other  aproach

I tried to have different state  machines in one riv file

Comment: I am assuming you are assets files, maybe you can try network(online) version or split into different rive files.